# Java program doesn't start from beginning, though I am trying to tell it to

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Basically, I am trying to create a test class using the main method. Depending on user input, the program is supposed to follow a certain sequence of steps, and then at the end, I'm trying to get the program to start from the beginning again (i.e., ask the first question at the beginning of the program, without actually having to quit the program and start it up again).

I have done something like this in the past, and I'm trying to do it the same way as before, but it's not working this time for some reason.

Here's a basic gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Payroll {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int steps = 0;

        while(steps == 0) {
        <Execute this code>
        steps = 1;
        }

        while(steps == 1) {
        <Execute this code>
        steps = 2;
        }

        while(steps == 2) {
        <Execute this code>
        steps = 0; //go back to the beginning
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the program reaches the step that says "steps = 0," it exits entirely, instead of going back to the beginning like I expected it to.

Does anybody know how to do what I'm trying to make it do?

Comment: have you considered using separate methods for each step and linking them together like step0>-step1->step2->step0. I think it would look much cleaner that way

Comment: @user189 Better you first check condition with if statement and then follow the sequence you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the three while loops in another while loop, extending from `while(steps == 0)` to after the closing brace `}` of `while(steps == 2)`.

The new while loop can have the condition `steps == 0` if you want the `steps == 2` loop to control the flow. Then you can set steps to -1 to escape the enclosing loop as well as the `steps == 2` loop. Like this:

```
while(steps == 0) {
    while(steps == 0) { /* ... */ }
    while(steps == 1) { /* ... */ }
    while(steps == 2) { /* ... */ } // this loop sets steps back to 0 to keep
                                    // looping, or it sets steps to -1 to quit
}
```

Comment: although this will work, its very odd...I would prefer one while loop with if conditions, its more readable

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it wouldnt start from the begining. What you are doing is checking the condition in three separate and independent while loops. If three of them fails, it should exit. There is nothing wrong with the functionality. as @irrelephant said you can enclose the the three while loops in another while loop.  
I would recommend a switch with three cases inside a single while loop.

Comment: better yet, do while. I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve using this code, but do while is even better

Answer (score 0):

How is your code any different than:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        <Execute step == 0 code>
        <Execute step == 1 code>
        <Execute step == 2 code>
}
```

In which case isn't it basically:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean done = false;

        while(!(done)) {
            <Execute step == 0 code>
            <Execute step == 1 code>
            <Execute step == 2 code>

            if(some condition) {
                done = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested looping is not advisable though. Try recursion. Using loops this is how I would do it. As long as step=0 the code keeps on repeating.

```
public class Payroll {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int steps = 0;
        while (steps == 0) {

            while (steps == 0) {
                <Execute this code>
                steps = 1;

            }

            while (steps == 1) {
                <Execute this code>
                steps = 2;

            }

            while (steps == 2) {
                 <Execute this code>
                steps = 0; //go back to the beginning
            }
        }
    }
}
```